# How to avoid repeating expressions when analysing data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nosql, expression

I'm new to programming and was asked to write some code to analyze a NoSQL database and make a dashboard. The task involves generating numbers of rows meeting certain criteria.

I decided to scan my database, put it in pandas dataframe and run .query() on it for readability. I've also heard good things about speed in pandas. However, I will need to repeat my code a lot to get all the fields needed, for example:

```
data1=df.query("a > 0").shape[0]  
data2=df.query("a > 0 & d=='yes'").shape[0]  
data3=df.query("a > 0 & d=='no'").shape[0]
```

It gets even worse with if-statements. Is there a less repetitive, more DRY way of doing that? One thing I came up with is a "table of expressions", below in pseudocode. Is there a way to do something like that in python? Or something better maybe?

```
                where a > 0    where b > 0     where c == 1
all results        3                7              5
where d=='yes'     1                3              4
where d=='no'      2                4              1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest extracting the repeated parts into a function:

```py
def get_result_size(cond1, cond2):
    return df.query(f"{cond1} & {cond2}").shape[0]
```

Then you can re-write your first example as

```py
data1=get_result_size("a > 0", 'True')
data2=get_result_size("a > 0", "d=='yes'")
data3=get_result_size("a > 0", "d=='no'")
```

To produce a table of results, you can write two loops, one within the other. The outer loop loops across your rows. The inner loop loops across the columns.

Note that using query() like this is not very efficient - Pandas is recomputing the same thing many times. For example, the above code evaluates `a > 0` against the entire dataframe 3 times, even though it only needs to be done once. That may be ok for your application, though.

Comment: thanks! Can you tell me more about what would me efficient? Something like this? `data1=df.query("a > 0")`  `data1a=data1.shape[0]`
`data1b=data1.query("d=='yes'").shape[0]`  `data1c=data1.query("d=='no'").shape[0]`

Comment: Yes, that would be more efficient, but give your variables actual names. There's an infamous quote about this: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Comment: I ended up doing that and using nice variable names AND also adding comments for different stages. can sleep safely now ;)